# Solving 2nd order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the  following PDE

$$\frac{\partial^{2}Z}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{y^{2} - 1}{(y^{2} + 1 )^{2}}$$

I have expanded the numerator as $y^{2} + 1 - 2$ and separated the fraction but after that I couldn't integrate the 2nd term. Please help me.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can learn how to use mathjax for formula.

Comment: @Bacon The denominator is $y^2 + 1$ not $y + 1$.

Comment: @Mattos Brainmelt moment...

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\partial^{2}Z}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{y^{2} - 1}{(y^{2} + 1 )^{2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x } = \int \frac{y^{2} - 1}{(y^{2} + 1 )^{2}}dy+f(x)=-\frac{y}{1+y^2}+f(x)$$
With arbitrary function $f$.
$$Z=\int\left(-\frac{y}{1+y^2}+f(x) \right)dx =-\frac{xy}{1+y^2}+F(x)+G(y)$$
With arbitrary functions $F$ and $G$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the second step of finding ∂Z/∂x ?

Comment: What is the problem ? The integral ?

Comment: Yes. Please show me the steps in finding the integral

Comment: $$\frac{y^2-1}{(y^2+1)^2}=\frac{-(y^2+1)+2y^2}{(y^2+1)^2}=
\frac{-1}{y^2+1}+\frac{2y^2}{(y^2+1)^2}$$
$$(uv)'=u'v+v'u \quad\text{Let}\quad
\begin{cases} u'=-1 \\ v=\frac{1}{y^2+1}\end{cases} \quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases} u=-y\\ v'=\frac{-2y}{(y^2+1)^2} \end{cases}\quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases} u'v=\frac{-1}{y^2+1} \\ v'u=\frac{2y^2}{(y^2+1)^2}\end{cases}$$
$$u'v+v'u=\frac{-1}{y^2+1}+\frac{2y^2}{(y^2+1)^2} = (uv)' =\left((-y)\frac{1}{y^2+1}\right)'$$
$$\frac{y^2-1}{(y^2+1)^2}=\left(\frac{-y}{y^2+1}\right)' \quad\to\quad \int \frac{y^2-1}{(y^2+1)^2}dy=\frac{-y}{y^2+1}+C$$